# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ( upon React Build in server

Tags: reactjs, build

I am building my React project locally and it works fine (tested running it with http-server). However, when I move the build file to my ubuntu server, it throws this **error** in the console:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'** (and the page does not load):

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?
The version of the main file is correct and checked nginx config and it is pointing to the build folder index.html.

This is what my build/index.html file looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#1975ff" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:ital,wght@0,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Proof of Play</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Proof of Play" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Proof of Play" />
    <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.6df388fa.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/css/main.d0aa35e2.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include your errors as text and not as an image.  Also what does your js file look like?

Comment: What does the response look like when you request `main.6df388fa.js`? (check the `Network` tab, click on the file name, then see the `Response` part)

Comment: @ewokx the error in text was already there: caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.6df388fa.js:1:1)

you mean my main.6df388fa.js? locally it's js, but from the console, it looks exactly like my HTML file

Comment: That means when you request the JS file, the Ubuntu server-side code sends you the index.html file instead.

Comment: Response: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#1975ff"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:ital,wght@0,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/><title>Proof of Play</title><meta name="description" content="Proof of Play"/><meta name="keywords" content="Proof of Play"/><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.f2130209.js"></script>

Comment: <link href="/static/css/main.d0aa35e2.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>

Comment: Does the same thing happen with the response for `/static/css/main.d0aa35e2.css`?

Comment: fails to load response for /static/css/main.d0aa35e2.css

Comment: I guess it's something with NGINX config for the subdirectories

Comment: @gabrielcon6: Did you figure out the problem ? I also run into the same issue like you

Comment: I think it was something with my machine. My coworker was able to redeploy it and after that it was fine for me as well